# Forced to exercise gap options

Tags: options

I was reading a textbook and came across some surprising stuff in the section about gap options.

> Let $X$ be a  payoff function such that $X=\Big\{\matrix{0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  , \ \ \ \ S(T)\leq K_2 \cr  S(T)-K_1\ \ \ \ ,\ \ \ \ \ S(T)> K_2}$

The payoff would be negative if $K_2<S(T)< K_1$. The textbook says:

> Notice that sometimes the option holder is forced to exercise at a loss! Perhaps the name "option" is a misnomer.

This seems surprising.  Is it true that gap options can incur loss for the option holder beyond the initial price?  Can you be "forced" to exercise options?

I looked online and didn't find anything.  Also, feel free to edit/migrate if necessary.

Comment: So trigger is $K_2$ and strike price is $K_1$. Suppose $S(0) = 100$, $K_1 = 1000$ and $K_2 = 0$. For a Gap call option, as long as $S(t) < 1000$, you will certainly lose money on the option. So the option price should be negative.

Comment: @Joseph Malle Which textbook?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Actex's book for exam MFE by Johnny Li

Answer (score 1):

Trigger contracts certainly exist and sometimes the trigger is out of the money and so yes the holder loses out. I have seen traded swaps that cancel when a reference rate is passed and the cancelling is disadvantageous.

Stop thinking of the contracts as "options" and start thinking of them as derivatives.

Comment: Do gap options usually have trigger contracts as described in the question?